# Java gives a JVM error upon closing the frame

Tags: java, linux, jvm, lwjgl

I'm using Ubuntu OS. Everything works properly. Once I try to close my LWJGL window, it closes also giving me this error. I have no idea what it means.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f59f2acbc58, pid=8351, tid=140024626677504
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x33c58]  XQueryExtension+0x28
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try     "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/chris/Desktop/BasicGame/hs_err_pid8351.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I understand I should enable the core dump, but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: JVM errors, always like a error machine.

Comment: You can try and take a peek at */home/chris/Desktop/BasicGame/hs_err_pid8351.log*'s content.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't take them serous unless they come all the time/every time.